# Rails trying to use html in a f.label tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<label ...>First name<em>*</em></label>
<input ... />
```

with this:

```
<%= d.label :first_name do %>First Name<em>*</em><% end %>
<%= d.text_field :first_name, :required => "required" %>
```

but it's actually producing:

```
First Name
<em>*</em>
<label ...>
    First Name
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input .../>
```

How can i get the html output that i'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with raw

```
<%= d.label :first_name, raw("First Name<em>*</em>") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the label content as a second argument to the block, and use `.html_safe` to prevent it from being encoded:

```
<%= d.label :first_name, "First Name<em>*</em>".html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

While both of these answers get the job done, it is not really the "most correct" way from a web design perspective.

Instead, consider giving the label an html class like "required". Then in your CSS, define a selector for label elements of the "required" class that adds a * and styles it as you wish.

Here's some SCSS from one of my projects:

```
.required::before {
        content: '*';
        color: $orange;
        margin-right: 2px;
        position: relative;
        left: -2px;
      };
```

Comment: Is this cross browser compatible in IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome, FF, Safari?

Comment: Probably? That wasn't a concern for me so you'd have to test on your own. This is pretty simple CSS stuff though so I'm sure it works without much hassle.